# Error while making an API request in Outlook add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am working on a Outlook add-in (JS add-in with Yeoman Generator) which fetches the data from an API and show it in a task pane.

I am able to get the response from one of the API, but for the other I am getting the below error in Outlook Client and as well as in OWA in IE. But it works well in OWA in Chrome.

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

taskpane.html
```

I have added all the domains in AppDomains list in the manifest. CORS is also enabled on the backend server.

Is there any additional configuration to be done ?

Comment: Did you try to use Fiddler for debugging your web calls?

Comment: Yes, from Fiddler I am getting the correct response. Only from IE it is failing

Comment: Are you on Windows 10? What is your version and build number of Outlook Client. You can find that by going to File > Office Account and under the About Outlook section.

Comment: Hi, I am on Windows 10 V1809 and Outlook Client V 2005 (Build 12827.20268). It is working fine in Chrome. But it fails in IE, so fails in Outlook Client as well. Is there any specific header that needs to be added during the API request ?

Comment: You most likely have to add the domain(s) to the list of trusted sites in IE, by adding them under IE's Internet Options > Security > Trusted Sites menu. A possible workaround is to upgrade to a newer Windows and Office, so add-ins are rendered using Edge Webview instead of IE. Details about what versions that Webview are supported can be found [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/).

Comment: Also can compare Fiddler (which acts as a reverse proxy) with the built-in F12 network tab trace.  Sounds like authentication is required for your API service, but what exactly is the authentication?  Check the requests with the 401 response and see what authentication is being requested, and what authentication is being sent back on the next request.  Is the API hosted somewhere in a trusted forest, and you are riding on network logon credentials?

Comment: Hi @BrianClink , yes the API uses AAD authentication. But even when we remove the authentication from the API, the request from add-in still fails.

Comment: Hi @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT , Added the add-in url and the api url to the Trusted Sites and still the same issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on a simple webpage in an IE browser with the same code (outside of an add-in)?

Comment: Hi, Outside the add-in , we were able to call the API successfully.

Comment: It's likely some issue with IE settings or on that computer blocking the issue. It's hard to tell what it may be though. You should look at your fiddler logs as recommended above, and see if the logs provide any clues/guidance as to what may be blocking the calls.